# Nativescript moving back result page is blank

Tags: listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

If you select a train you will go to this page where you see your transfers.

If you click on the train you will go to the other page where see where the train stops.

But If you press back (system back) you will get a blank page see picture on the bottom.

I have no idea why this happens.

The blank page is the `ListView` he doesn't render.

```
<FlexboxLayout dock="center" class="dock-center">
                <ListView for="item in $props.selectTravelDetails.Routes" marginLeft="5%" @itemTap="navigateToRouteDetails">
                    <v-template>
                        <FlexboxLayout height="180" flexDirection="column">
                            <FlexboxLayout height="10">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout class="trainDetails">
                                <FlexboxLayout class="trainTimeDetails">
                                    <Label :text="item.TimeInfos[item.departureStation].DepTime"></Label>
                                    <Label class="fas" :color="$props.language.trainTypes[item.trainType].color" :text="'\uf238' | unescape"></Label>
                                    <Label :text="item.TimeInfos[item.arrivalStation].ArrTime"></Label>
                                </FlexboxLayout>
                                <FlexboxLayout class="route">
                                    <Label class="far" :text="'\uf111' | unescape"></Label>
                                    <FlexboxLayout class="template-line">
                                        <Label class="line"></Label>
                                    </FlexboxLayout>
                                    <Label class="far" :text="'\uf111' | unescape"></Label>
                                </FlexboxLayout>
                                <FlexboxLayout class="trainDestArrDetails">
                                    <Label v-if="$store.state.language === 'ZH'" class="departure" :text="$store.state.searchFile[item.departureStation].站名"></Label>
                                    <Label v-else class="departure" :text="$store.state.searchFile[item.departureStation].eng站名"></Label>
                                    <FlexboxLayout class="trainDetailsIcons">
                                        <FlexboxLayout class="information">
                                            <Label :text="$props.language.trainTypes[item.trainType].name + ' ' + item.Train"></Label>
                                            <FlexboxLayout class="trainIcons">
                                                <Label v-if="item.BreastFeed === 'Y'" class="fas" :text="'\uf77c' | unescape"></Label>
                                                <Label v-if="item.Dinning === 'Y'" class="fas" :text="'\uf2e7' | unescape"></Label>
                                                <Label v-if="item.Cripple === 'Y'" class="fas" :text="'\uf193' | unescape"></Label>
                                                <Label v-if="item.Bike === 'Y'" class="fas" :text="'\uf206' | unescape"></Label>
                                            </FlexboxLayout>
                                        </FlexboxLayout>
                                        <FlexboxLayout class="navigation">
                                            <Label class="fas" :text="'\uf054' | unescape"></Label>
                                        </FlexboxLayout>
                                    </FlexboxLayout>
                                    <Label v-if="$store.state.language === 'ZH'" class="arrival" :text="$store.state.searchFile[item.arrivalStation].站名"></Label>
                                    <Label v-else class="arrival" :text="$store.state.searchFile[item.arrivalStation].eng站名"></Label>
                                </FlexboxLayout>
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout height="10">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                        </FlexboxLayout>
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
            </FlexboxLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

## **UPDATE**

When I click the white space where normal should be a train I will still go in the details.

Comment: Can you share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj the problem is I can't take those 2 screens out of my application. Is there any way I can debug something for you're thinking about.

Comment: @Manoj also see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue why I went blank is because of the inline CSS:

```
        <FlexboxLayout dock="center" class="dock-center">
               <ListView for="item in $props.selectTravelDetails.Routes" marginLeft="5%" @itemTap="navigateToRouteDetails">
                    <v-template>
                        <FlexboxLayout height="180" flexDirection="column">
                            <FlexboxLayout height="10">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout class="trainDetails">
                               // some other code
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout height="10">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                        </FlexboxLayout>
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
          </FlexboxLayout>
```

so I changed it to:

```
           <FlexboxLayout dock="center" class="dock-center">
               <ListView for="item in $props.selectTravelDetails.Routes" class="listTrain" @itemTap="navigateToRouteDetails">
                    <v-template>
                        <FlexboxLayout class="oneTrainElement" flexDirection="column">
                            <FlexboxLayout class="whiteSpace">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout class="trainDetails">
                               // some other code
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                            <FlexboxLayout class="whiteSpace">
                            </FlexboxLayout>
                        </FlexboxLayout>
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
            </FlexboxLayout>

    .dock-center .listTrain{
        margin-left: 5%;
    }

    .dock-center .listTrain .oneTrainElement{
        height: 180;
    }

    .dock-center .listTrain .whiteSpace{
        height: 10;
    }
```